# Affix menu on top permanently (without disappearing for a sec)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to affix menu nav bar on top fixed, but somehow the bar layout and "social icons" and "search box" I have get all messed up. I tried changing line 7 from relative to fixed position, but no luck.
Basically what I have now is the menu is on top, when you scroll down, the menu disappears for a while and then pops up again to stay affixed on top when scrolling down. No clue why the menu disappears for a sec when scrolling down to come back, but basically now I want the menu nav bar fixed on top permanently and not disappear for a sec when scrolling down. And ofcourse the current layout / width and all to stay in tact. Is it possible to achieve this somehow?

My BOOTPLY::: [BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/s6Ey64BSaj)

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

.menu-container {
    background-color:#000;
    border-bottom:4px dashed #FFBB3A;
    min-height:20px;
    position:relative;
}
```

```html
 <header id="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static">
                        
                        <div class="clearfix menu-container">
                            <div class="pull-right clearfix toggle_btn_wrap">
                                <a class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-left brand-name">
                                <h1>MENU</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix prevent-float"></div>
                            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      <div class="clearfix search_and_social">
                            <div class="clearfix navbar navbar-custom-search">
                                search box
                            </div>
                            <div class="clearfix navbar navbar-custom-social">
                                social icons
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
<div class="content"> CONTENT </div>
```

Comment: You need to apply `position: fixed;` to a less deeply nested element, something like `#nav`.

Comment: @hungerstar - I added my test-site where you can see the problem better if you scroll down slowly and look at the menu nav behavior.

Comment: The menu jumps because there is some javascript controlling it's position. Not sure if that's a plugin or what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using the [Bootstrap Affix Plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) and don't have it configured properly or it is doing something a little different from what you expected. The *Affix* plugin is setup to trigger a *"sticky"* header after scrolling some distance or to some element.

This will get you what is going on in [this Bootstrap example](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/).

**Solution**

Remove/disable *Affix* plugin.

Add `.navbar-fixed-top` to your `#nav` element. Then add `padding-top` to the body element that is equal to the height of your `#nav` element, which is currently `181px`.